# updating unidirectional many to one join column value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Below are two entity classes. The child class has an unidirectional `@ManyToOne` mapping.

PlantDetails :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PLANT_DETAILS", uniqueConstraints={ @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"PLANT"})})
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler", "ignoreUnknown = true"})
public class PlantDetails implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PLANT_ID")
    private Long plantId;
    @Column(name = "PLANT")
    private String plant;
    @Column(name = "PLANT_DETAILS")
    private String plant_Details;
    @Column(name = "LOCATION")
    private String location;
    @JsonCreator
    public PlantDetails(  @JsonProperty("plantId") Long plantId, 
                          @JsonProperty("plant") String plant,
                          @JsonProperty("plant_Details") String plant_Details,
                          @JsonProperty("location") String location )

                  {
        this.plantId = plantId;
        this.plant = plant;
        this.plant_Details = plant_Details;
        this.location = location;
    }
```

LineDetails:

```
@Entity
    @Table(name = "LINE_DETAILS", uniqueConstraints={ @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "PLANT", "LINE_NAME" })})
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler", "ignoreUnknown = true"})
        public class LineDetails implements Serializable {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "LINE_ID")
        private Long lineId;

        @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="PLANT", referencedColumnName = "PLANT")
        private PlantDetails plantDetails;

        @Column(name = "LINE_NAME")
        private String lineName;
        @Column(name = "LINE_DESCRIPTION")
        private String lineDescription;

        @JsonCreator
        public LineDetails( @JsonProperty("lineId") Long lineId, 
                            @JsonProperty("lineName") String lineName,
                            @JsonProperty("lineDescription") String lineDescription) {

            this.lineId = lineId;
            this.lineName = lineName;
            this.lineDescription = lineDescription;
        }
```

I am trying to do the basic CRUD operations. The following code updates the child table.I can update the columns by using the setters. But i am not able to update the `@JoinColumn` field "plant" as i don't have it in the `@jsoncreator` constructor in the entity class.How can i update that field?

While creating/inserting a record, i set the `@JoinColumn` field "plant" by getting its value from plantdetails entity id column and not through `@jsoncreator`.

In DAOimpl

```
    @Override
        public void updateLineDetails(LineDetails lineDetails) {

            Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

            LineDetails existinglineDetails = (LineDetails) session.get(LineDetails.class, 
            lineDetails.getLineId());
            existinglineDetails.setLineName(lineDetails.getLineName());
            existinglineDetails.setLineDescription(lineDetails.getLineDescription());

            session.update(existinglineDetails);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass somehow the value represented by this field:

```
@Column(name = "PLANT")
private String plant;
```

I would in general not pass data through the entity structure itself. I would create additional `LineDetailsInfo` class that would hold all the info in plain fields.

```
public class LineDetailsInfo{

        @JsonCreator
        public LineDetails( @JsonProperty("lineId") Long lineId, 
                            @JsonProperty("lineName") String lineName,
                            @JsonProperty("lineDescription") String lineDescription,
                            @JsonProperty("plant") String plant) {
            this.plant = plant;
            this.lineId = lineId;
            this.lineName = lineName;
            this.lineDescription = lineDescription;
        }
}
```

Then you would need to query for that particular `PlantDetails` entity and update the parent entity accordingly:

```
    @Override
    public void updateLineDetails(LineDetailsInfo lineDetailsInfo) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        PlantDetails pd = (PlantDetails)session.createQuery("from PlantDetails where plant = :plant")
                                 .setString("plant", lineDetailsInfo.getPlant()).uniqueResult();
        LineDetails existinglineDetails = (LineDetails) session.get(LineDetails.class, 
        lineDetailsInfo.getLineId());
        existinglineDetails.setLineName(lineDetailsInfo.getLineName());
        existinglineDetails.setPlantDetails(pd);

       existinglineDetails.setLineDescription(lineDetailsInfo.getLineDescription())

        session.update(existinglineDetails);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice workaround. I should do other CRUD operations though the new  LineDetailsInfo class or using old LineDetails class.

Comment: Great. Glad it helped you out

Comment: sorry to bother you. please can you show for Create(persist). I could not figure out replacement for 'LineDetails existinglineDetails = (LineDetails) session.get(LineDetails.class, 
        lineDetailsInfo.getLineId());'